# On change ng-model value should be change

Tags: angularjs

I have below code.

```
 <td class="minwd100">
                       <select class="form-control" id="invoice_id" name="invoice_id" ng-options="invoice as invoice.invoice_number+ ' - '+invoice.client_name+' - '+invoice.invoice_converted_total for invoice in approved_invoices track by invoice.invoice_id" ng-model="approved_invoices.invoice_id" ng-change="changeInvoice(approved_invoices.invoice_id)"></select>
                    </td>
                      <td class="minwd100"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="payment_amount" ng-model="payment_data.payment_amount.value" name="payment_amount" placeholder="Enter {{form_data.payment_amount.label}}" ng-focus="form_data.payment_amount.error = ''" /></td>
                      <td class="minwd100"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="payment_conversion" ng-model="payment_data.payment_conversion_rate.value" name="payment_conversion" placeholder="Enter {{form_data.payment_conversion_rate.label}}" ng-focus="form_data.payment_conversion_rate.error = ''" /></td>
                      <td class="minwd100"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="payment_converted_amount" ng-model="payment_data.payment_converted_amount.value" name="payment_converted_amount" placeholder="Enter {{form_data.payment_converted_amount.label}}" ng-focus="form_data.payment_converted_amount.error = ''" ng-readonly="true"/></td>
                      <td class="wd80">
                          <div class="dt-options">
                              <a href ng-if="$index === form.payments.length - 1" ng-click="addContact()" title="Add Contact"><i class="fa fa-plus fa-lg"></i></a>
                              <a href ng-if="form.payments.length > 1" ng-click="removeContact($index)" title="Remove Contact"><i class="fa fa-trash-o fa-lg"></i></a>
                          </div>
                      </td>

<script>

$scope.changeInvoice = function (selectedItem){
      $scope.payment_data.payment_amount.value = selectedItem.invoice_converted_total;
      $scope.payment_data.payment_conversion_rate.value = selectedItem.invoice_conversion_rate;
      $scope.payment_data.payment_converted_amount.value = selectedItem.invoice_converted_balance;
      $scope.client_id = selectedItem.client_id;
      $scope.payment_data.invoice_id.value = selectedItem.invoice_id;
    };

 $scope.addContact = function() {
        $scope.form.payments.push({invoice_id: '', payment_amount: '', payment_conversion: '', payment_converted_amount: ''});
    };
    $scope.removeContact = function(index) {
        $scope.form.payments.splice(index, 1);
    };

</script>
```

To each change, value should be triggered for each input, But now whenever I add new row, its reflect old value itself please help. I have added image also please refere that.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What is the collection that you are iterating through?

"To each change, value should be triggered for each input, But now whenever I add new row, its reflect old value itself please help. I have added image also please refere that."

Are you saying that when you change one row every row changes? That is how I am understanding it. My guess is that all of the items in the collection are referencing the same object and you need to refer to the specific item within the collection.

I recently set up a model that had a form where you could add many associations so when adding a new association to the form I had to use a unique key to refer to the hash. I.e.:

```
$scope.addNewPartToAssembly = function(part) {
  $scope.form.assembly.assembly_parts[part.id] = {
    ...
  }
}
```

I'm just kind of guessing at your problem because to me it seems incomplete, maybe somebody else could resolve it with what's provided. Either way, hope that helps.